# Как вывести список в таком виде?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, коллекции

Как мне вывести список в таком виде?

[1]

[1, 2]

[1, 2, 3]

```
x = int(input())
n = [i*[i] for i in range(1, x+1)]
for i in n:
    print(i, sep='\n')

Input:
3
Output:
[1]
[2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот еще один простой вариант:

```
x = int(input('Введите число: '))
my_list = []

for i in range(1, x+1):
    my_list.append(i)
    print(my_list)
```

Comment: код работает не правильно

Comment: @finally код работает согласно ТЗ: https://ideone.com/ymUZG1 Что конкретно вы видите тут неправильного?

Answer (score 2):

Такое удобно через `range` генерировать:

```
x = 3

for i in range(1, x+1):
    print(list(range(1, i+1)))
```

Результат:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: это не то, чего хотел добиться автор

Comment: @finally, поэтому вы и поставили минусы? :) То, что вы выводите именно `[1] [2, 2] [3, 3, 3]` автор **уже** реализовала, строка `[i*[i] for i in range(1, x+1)]`. Поэтому, я считаю, что это вы сделали не то, что хотел автор :) Тем более, не случайно ведь в вопросе в начале было `[1] [1, 2] [1, 2, 3]`